# Archiving Script is archiving 2 rows instead of one

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a script that works by recognising I have selected 'Archive' in a drop down box that sits in Column 16 and then pasting that row onto another tab and deleting it from the main tracker

The issue I'm having is that it is sometimes archiving 2 rows instead of 1. I can't seem to find a common denominator in this and this same script works with other docs without an issue.

Can anyone see any errors that I'm missing?

Spreadsheet in Google Sheets: [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QCFvG3Ye9Gzial5ZGi-56RlrsjeJ5aUdzTnJm1RYkSQ/edit#gid=0)

If it makes a difference, I have two others set up to look for 'Leaver' and 'Withdrew Application' in that drop down column as well. All three are separate scripts with seperate triggers (on edit)

```js
function onEdit() {
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Tracker";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 16; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "Archive"
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Archive";
  Logger.log(valueToWatch);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

   if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share Spreadsheet example (url) please? I can't reproduce your error but what I saw for now is that `getLastRow() + 1` could give you errors, as the lastRow is the last row, and you are accesing undefined range?

Comment: I tried taking out the +1 to see if that made a difference, and the same error still occurs. What doesn't seem to make sense is that is happens on some rows, but not on others?

Comment: can you share Spreadsheet example? I just can't reproduce an error, because for me it works fine without `+ 1`, waiting for your response

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QCFvG3Ye9Gzial5ZGi-56RlrsjeJ5aUdzTnJm1RYkSQ/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the provided example,

I tested your [Google Sheets sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QCFvG3Ye9Gzial5ZGi-56RlrsjeJ5aUdzTnJm1RYkSQ/edit#gid=0), and it didn't give me any errors.

Here is the procedure:

1. Click on D2
2. Select Archive sheet
3. Wait for Apps Script to load

It didn't work for me if I do 10 clicks per seconds.